# Problem 2h. Munkres Topology Section 1.1 Confirmation

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, self-learning

I'm learning (or trying to) topology from Munkres' Topology. I believe I've solved 2h in Section 1.1, but I wanted to confirm with someone that I am doing it right. Here it is:

> $ A\cup (B - C) = (A \cup B) - (A \cup C)$

I believe that this is false, and here's why. On the RHS, you have elements in $A \cap C$ that you don't have on the LHS. Therefore, I believe that there is a backwards implication ( $\impliedby$). Can someone confirm or tell me where my logic is wrong? Thank you so much :)

Comment: If you think it's false, prove it by giving a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $B=\{3, 4, 5\}$ and $C=\varnothing$.  Then $2 \notin (A\cup B) - (A \cup C)$  yet $2 \in A \cup (B-C)$.  So, I'm inclined to believe you are right (if you've interpreted the problem correctly).

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it.